# How is a beta particle an electron?

Tags: radioactivity, nuclear-chemistry

I've previously read that a beta particle is just a fast moving electron or positron that emerges out of a neutron and turns it into a proton.

I'm really confused by this since particle physics states that an electron is a fundamental particle and neutrons
and protons are made of another fundamental particle, quarks.

Comment: So what is the problem? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles-de.svg

Comment: The OP thinks this interaction is mediated by photons but in fact it is mediated by Z bosons.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10453/understanding-beta-decay

Comment: I do not think that this question in any shape or form is a chemistry question. This is pure particle physics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an off-topics (Particle Physics) question.

Answer (score 3):

More a physics question, so I googled it: "quarks when neutron decays"

> [wikipedia: neutron] The decay of one of the neutron's down quarks into a lighter up quark can be achieved by the emission of a W boson. By this process, the Standard Model description of beta decay, the neutron decays into a proton (which contains one down and two up quarks), an electron, and an electron antineutrino.

And here is a picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A proton or a neutron can become a neutron or proton by a process called neutrino capture in which due to conservation of charge a electron or a positron must be emitted.But this is not the complete story.

The complete story is this:

[image]

A neutron can capture a neutrino and with the help of the **weak interaction** it is transformed to a electron and a proton.

For more reading :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_detector

Comment: p+ is a proton.